# Requests in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have three objects. I am trying to fing the parents who haven't got a job. I am writing this code:

```
db.getCollection('students').find({
   'parents.profession':{$exists: false}
})
```

I have no mistakes, but it is loking for me users who haven't got a parents. What am i doing wrong

My Objects:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("60c1bd314ed90f98fbbf9d5b"),
"name" : "Ivan",
"class" : 2.0,
"lessons" : [ 
    "basic"
],
"avgScore" : 4.2,
"parents" : [ 
    {
        "gender" : "male",
        "name" : "Ivan",
        "profession" : "trainer"
    }, 
    {
        "gender" : "female",
        "name" : "Vika"
    }
]
}

{
"_id" : ObjectId("60c1bd314ed90f98fbbf9d5d"),
"name" : "Kostya",
"class" : 2.0,
"lessons" : [ 
    "basic"
],
"avgScore" : 4.24,
"parents" : [ 
    {
        "gender" : "male",
        "name" : "Ivan",
        "profession" : "blogger"
    }, 
    {
        "gender" : "male",
        "name" : "Andriy",
        "profession" : "blogger"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: How did you resolve your last question you have deleted? I posted an answer, and I am curious about the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$elemMatch`:

```
db.collection.find({
  "parents": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      profession: {
        $exists: false
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Here is the working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/XT8JJdZ9L5H